# How to join large number of tables without copying and pasting the same body multiple times?

Tags: sql, sas

I am writing a SAS code using `PROC SQL` query that will be calling a total 
of 32,448+ tables. I am trying to avoid having to copy and paste the same code 30K+ times. I am writing the code in `PROC SQL` because SAS is new to me but I will take an answer in SAS or `SQL`.

Any suggestions or shortcuts?

thanks,

Comment: @GordonLinoff, likely because this question reads as a code-writing request: *I will take an answer in SAS or SQL*. OP does not post any code attempt or [MCVE]. And it lingers in *too broad a question* even the *[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)* as there are multiple ways to do this in SAS or SQL. We welcome new SO members but they should take the time to learn [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Parfait . . . A downvote is only going to discourage someone from using the site.  Provide simple explanations of what is wanted or expected.  Further, I don't see how asking for a short-cut is a "code writing" project at all.

Comment: To get a specific answer provide a specific example.  How are the tables named? 
Is there a pattern in the names such that the names could be constructed?  or do you need to discover them from the disk?  If you need to discover them is there a way to tell which ones go together? Perhaps based on a common prefix. Show what method you are currently attempting to use to combine

Comment: What kind of join ? Natural join ? Are there keys ? Are you really unioning and not joining ? Are you flattening a snowflake data model ?

Comment: There're certainly ways to do this that are efficient, and as Gordon points out in his answer it's likely there are better ways to structure your overall approach.  But either way I think you'll be best off giving some more detail, including an example (say, show 3 or 4 tables that exemplify what you're doing plus code).  See [mcve] and [ask] for more details on how to improve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your data model if you have 32,448 tables.  In all likelihood, these are just repetitions of one table, split by some factor -- zip code, date, or the like.  They should be stored in a single table.

You have another problem.  According to the [documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p0hwg3z33gllron184mzdoqwpe3j.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en):

> The FROM clause can itself contain a query expression that takes an
>   optional table alias. This type of nested query expression is called
>   an in-line view. An in-line view is any query expression that would be
>   valid in a CREATE VIEW statement. PROC SQL can support many levels of
>   nesting, but it is limited to 256 tables in any one query. The
>   256-table limit includes underlying tables that can contribute to
>   views that are specified in the FROM clause.

So, you probably can't do what you want using proc sql.

Comment: `PROC SQL can support many levels of nesting,` Maybe in theory. In practice, PROC SQL is limited to two or three range table entries. (SAS is more or less schemaless, so it is impossible to find an optimal plan, except for a trivial two-table join)

Comment: @joop . . . You would have to take that up with SAS.  I'm just quoting from the documentation.

Comment: I am trying to append or concatenate about 3 tables that get updated weekly over the course of two plus years, hence the 30k+ SAS Tables.

Comment: @dariocampelo . . . 3 tables generated weekly over 2 years is about 312 tables.  That still exceeds the threshold, but you should work on your estimation skills.  Your process should probably be to copy the tables into master tables, to facilitate querying, reporting, and analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the 256 PROC SQL limit. I am trying to append or concatenate about multiple tables that get updated weekly over the course of multiple years, hence the 2k to 30K+ SAS Tables. I don't know if I can create a separate table within SAS with all the table names and call them with a for loop of some kind in SAS?

Comment: @dariocampelo Since your operation appears to be `UNION (ALL)` SAS will have no problem in *concatenating* the files upto 255. A simple DATA step could do exactly the same, most probaly with the same nfile limit. (behind the curtain, PROC SQL is compiled into a (number of) DATA step(s), too)

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it is hard to provide any exact answer.  But in general in SAS it will be much easier to code this using normal SAS code rather than SQL.

Assuming by the word "table" you mean SAS dataset and further assuming that they are all in the same library (directory/folder) and share a unique common prefix (such as `week`) then the combination step could be as simple as:

```
libname mylib 'some folder name' ;
data want;
  set mylib.week: ;
run;
```